# Pandas pivot from long to wide mode with duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pandas df with attribute names in col1 and attribute values in col2. I would like to:

1. Pivot all unique rows in col1 to columns in the df
2. Assign the corresponding values in col2 to rows

`pivot` does not work because there are duplicate values.

`pivot_table` does not work because `aggfunc` returns only means, etc, whereas I need all rows pivoted.

I did not have success with `melt` or `unstack`.

Original df:

```
col1    col2
attr1   2
attr2   6
attr3   3
...     ...
attr1   9
attr2   2
attr3   5
```

Desired output:

```
attr1    attr2    attr3
2        6        3
9        2        5
```

Comment: Without a reproducible example it's hard to help... But have you tried to [Transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) the dataframe with `.T`? - - nope, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `set_index`, `groupby` with `cumcount` and `unstack`:

```
df.set_index([df.groupby('col1').cumcount(),'col1'])['col2'].unstack()
```

Output:

```
col1 attr1 attr2 attr3
0        2     6     3
1        9     2     5
```

Comment: Works! I'm surprised this behavior isn't native to `pivot`.

Comment: @akr24 To use pivot you still much create the helper column to know how to define "rows" like this `df.assign(row=df.groupby('col1').cumcount()).pivot('row','col1')`

Comment: Nice solution, @ScottBoston! One quick question, though: how can we recover the index after this?

Comment: @mairan I am not sure what index you want to recover.  Can you start a new question showing your input dataframe and except out with your desired indexing.